# R as.POSIXct timezone issue

Tags: r, posixct

I'm confused by the as.POSIXct in R.

I use the following code to convert values in columns to one column with Date and Time.

```
  fname$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(fname$yy, fname$mm, fname$dd, fname$HH, fname$MM), format = "%y %m %d %H %M")
```

Then, I set a time limit for plotting.

```
  lims <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2015-10-23 4:00","2015-10-23 16:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) 
  Temp <- ggplot(DF, aes(x=DateTime, y=Temp)) + geom_line(aes(x=DateTime, y=Temp),colour="blue", alpha = 0.8) + scale_x_datetime(limits =lims, breaks=date_breaks("1 hour"), labels=date_format("%m/%d %H:%M")) + facet_wrap( ~ ID, ncol=4)
  Temp + geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2015-10-23 10:30")), linetype=4, colour="purple")
```

[image]

The time series starts at 10/23 08:00 instead of 10/23 4:00; ends at 10/23 20:00 instead of 10/23 16:00. The vertical line shows at 10/23 14:30 instead of 10/23 10:30. It is a 4-hour time shift!

What is that happened? How can I just show the right time series as the DateTime showed in the data frame? Please help me!

Thanks.

Comment: probably a timezone issue

Comment: Measurements were done at local time. The POSIXct did not use any time zone. Why not it just shows what the DateTime as it is in the data frame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `as.POSIXct` without specifying the timezone, it assumes the times you enter are utc and it also assumes you want them converted into the local timezone. Why it makes these often false assumptions is beyond me...
Try `as.POSIXct(..., tz=<enter your timezone>)`

If you do not know your timezone, `Sys.timezone(location = TRUE)` will tell you what your timezone is.

Comment: Great! It matches with with the GMT timezone. HOWEVER,   geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2015-10-23 10:30")) did not show where it should be. It is plotted at  2015-10-23 14:30. It should be at 2015-10-23 10:30. Any ideas?

Comment: @kuo-hsienchang same issue. Add a timezone to the `as.POSIXct` function.

Comment: I added "tz="UTC" to both of them. It did not work as I expected.

Comment: @Kuo-hsienchang No you should add your local timezone. If you you don't know what it is, try `Sys.timezone(location = TRUE)`